# When using pyenv, can different versions of python share the same third-party libraries such as numpy 1.15.1 and jupyter 1.0.1?

Tags: python, numpy, pyenv

I am using pyenv to control versions among 2.7.15 and 3.6.5. In both cases, I have to use `pip install numpy` to successfully `import numpy`. So I think there is some duplicate when using numpy for different versions of python because numpy can both support python2 and python3.

Is there any way that we can share those third-party libraries such numpy and jupyter among different versions of python when using pyenv ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Virtualenv doc](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/]):

> In all these cases, `virtualenv` can help you. It creates an environment that has its own installation directories, that doesn’t share libraries with other virtualenv environments (and optionally doesn’t access the globally installed libraries either).

You are using `pyenv` but it is the same. You can not share libs between different envs, since each one is completely separate and isolated